# What JAR is uka/transport/Transportable in?

Tags: java

I am getting this error and need to figure out which JAR to download.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uka/transport/Transportable
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: That? http://www.ipd.uka.de/JavaParty/download.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to google: https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=uka%2Ftransport%2FTransportable. It's first search result!

http://www.ipd.uka.de/JavaParty/ukatransport.html

Comment: There are a few different JARs at [JavaParty](http://www.ipd.uka.de/JavaParty/download.html). The JavaParty JAR (jp.jar) did not work. Inside the KaRMI Archive there are two JARs; karmi.jar and uka.jar. **uka.jar** solved this issue.

Comment: You can uncompress jar files and explore their content, or just use an IDE like IntelliJ which has a built-in decompiler since 14 version.